# Under what conditions can travellers from Germany be reimbursed in case of a travel warning?

Tags: international-travel, cancellations

According to [an article published on tagesschau.de 2020-06-10](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/reisewarnung-corona-103.html), travellers who book with a German provider are entitled to a refund if the *Auswärtiges Amt* (foreign office) issues a *Reisewarnung* (travel warning), but not if they issue a *Reisehinweis* (travel advisory) or the travel is booked with a non-German provider:

> Für den Fall einer Reisewarnung können Urlauber in der Regel kostenfrei stornieren. Das gilt für Buchungen nach deutschem Recht. Für Buchungen bei einem ausländischen Anbieter kann dagegen das Recht des dortigen Landes gelten.

My translation:

> For the situation of a travel warning, vacationers can normally cancel free of charge.  This applies for bookings according to German law.  For bookings with a foreign provider, the laws of the other country may apply.

What are the details of the rules being referred to here?  Does this apply to all modes of transportation regardless of how it was booked, or are there specific conditions that must be met?  For the sake of this question, assume the travel (such as flight) still occurs and therefore no compensation is due via that route.

There is [a question about flights here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38349/flight-ticket-reimbursement-after-travel-warning), but it appears the German law may be more generous (to the traveller) than the laws in other countries.  The details are not covered in [this question about COVID-19 cancellation refunds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155054/2509).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about nuances about Urlauber in German, but if it is referring to customers of packaged holidays, the EU Package Travel Directive and its German implementation (§§651a ff. BGB) apply.

In that case, §651h BGB provides for

> (1) Vor Reisebeginn kann der Reisende jederzeit vom Vertrag zurücktreten. Tritt der Reisende vom Vertrag zurück, verliert der Reiseveranstalter den Anspruch auf den vereinbarten Reisepreis. Der Reiseveranstalter kann jedoch eine angemessene Entschädigung verlangen. [...]
>
> (3) Abweichend von Absatz 1 Satz 3 kann der Reiseveranstalter keine Entschädigung verlangen, wenn am Bestimmungsort oder in dessen unmittelbarer Nähe unvermeidbare, außergewöhnliche Umstände auftreten, die die Durchführung der Pauschalreise oder die Beförderung von Personen an den Bestimmungsort erheblich beeinträchtigen. Umstände sind unvermeidbar und außergewöhnlich im Sinne dieses Untertitels, wenn sie nicht der Kontrolle der Partei unterliegen, die sich hierauf beruft, und sich ihre Folgen auch dann nicht hätten vermeiden lassen, wenn alle zumutbaren Vorkehrungen getroffen worden wären.
>
> *(1) Before the trip begins, the traveller can withdraw from the contract at any time. If the traveler withdraws from the contract, the tour operator loses the right to the agreed price. However, the tour operator can request reasonable compensation. [...]*
>
> *(3) Notwithstanding the third sentence in Absatz 1, the tour operator may not claim compensation if unavoidable, exceptional circumstances arise at or in the immediate vicinity of the destination which significantly affect the performance of the package or the transport of persons to the destination. Circumstances are unavoidable and exceptional within the meaning of this Subtitle if they are beyond the control of the party invoking them and their consequences could not have been avoided even if all reasonable precautions had been taken.*

Travel warnings are **indicative** ("in der Regel") of an unavoidable and exceptional circumstances that affects the performance/execution of the travel package.

> Reisewarnungen stellen aber ohnehin nur ein Indiz dar, sind also nicht allein ausschlaggebend für die Beantwortung der Frage, ob eine Pauschalreise kostenlos storniert werden kann oder nicht.
>
> *Travel warnings are only an indication anyway and are therefore not the only decisive factor in answering the question of whether a package tour can be canceled free of charge or not.*
>
> https://www.bmjv.de/DE/Themen/FokusThemen/Corona/Reiserecht/Corona_Reiserecht_node.html

Further rights to refund exist for general reasons of impossibility to perform a contract or receive a service/goods due to restrictions by the German government (but travel warning from the Foreign Office is not a travel ban).

> 2. Sie haben eine Pauschalreise gebucht? In folgenden Fällen entstehen keine Stornokosten
>
> Sie können zurücktreten, wenn im Reiseland sogenannte außergewöhnliche Umstände vorliegen, also zum Beispiel Krankheiten wie Covid19: Ein wichtiges Indiz sind Reisewarnungen des Auswärtigen Amtes. Aktuell gibt es eine Reisewarnung für alle Länder mit Ausnahme der Mitgliedsstaaten der Europäischen Union, der Schengen-assoziierten Staaten und des Vereinigten Königreiches - vorerst bis einschließlich 31. August. [...]
>
> 5. Was bedeutet das für Buchungen von Hotels oder Ferienhäusern?
>
> Können Sie Ihr Ziel aufgrund der Reisebeschränkungen der deutschen Regierung, eines Einreiseverbots oder der Lage der Unterkunft im Sperrgebiet nicht erreichen, können Sie nach deutschem Recht Ihre Unterkunft stornieren und Ihr Geld zurückverlangen. Wurde die Unterkunft direkt bei Anbietern im Ausland gebucht, kann ausländisches Recht gelten und die rechtliche Situation anders aussehen. [...]
>
> 6. Nur Flug gebucht - Ihre Rechte
>
> Wird ein Flug annulliert, erhalten Sie den Ticketpreis zurück.
>
> Soll ein Flug trotz Einreiseverbot am Zielort stattfinden, können Sie nach der Auffassung der Verbraucherzentrale ebenfalls Ihr Geld zurückverlangen.
>
> Der Flugverkehr ist derzeit stark eingeschränkt. Damit haben Sie in vielen Fällen gute Argumente, den Ticketpreis zurückzuverlangen.
>
> Aktuell wird jedoch angekündigt, dass der Flugverkehr wieder anlaufen soll. Informieren Sie sich regelmäßig über die gebuchte Verbindung.
>
> Fragen Sie bei der Airline nach. Viele Anbieter zeigen sich kulant. Mit einem Gutschein müssen Sie sich bei annullierten Flügen nicht zufriedengeben
>
> https://www.verbraucherzentrale-niedersachsen.de/themen/freizeit-reise/faq-reisen-coronavirus

Comment: Your first paragraph appears to refer to whether tour operators can claim compensation, rather than travellers?  And your final quote: *Soll ein Flug trotz Einreiseverbot am Zielort stattfinden, können Sie nach der Auffassung der Verbraucherzentrale ebenfalls Ihr Geld zurückverlangen* sounds relevant, but also vague.

Comment: @gerrit Tour operator cannot claim compensation from travellers = travellers can get a refund without cancellation fees.The flight part is vague, the consumer advice centre thinks it should allow you to get refund, but that's not legally obvious/certain or tested in court.